# error : cannnot the match data also cannot get value in $passwd

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, bootstrap-modal

*error:*cannot the get data from model so that i cannot match the old database data and new one.can not get success message
also cannot display any kind of error.can any help me.

**here is my** 
**controller**

```
public function changepassword(){
     $this->load->library('form_validation'); 
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('oldpassword', 'Current Password', 'required|alpha_numeric|min_length[1]|max_length[20]');
        if($this->form_validation->run()){
        $cur_password = $this->input->post('oldpassword');
        //echo $cur_password;
        $this->load->model('home_model');
        $userid = $this->session->userdata('username'); 
        //echo $userid; 
        $passwd = $this->home_model->checkOldPass($userid);
        echo $passwd;
        //echo $cur_password;
        if($passwd == $cur_password){ 
        echo 'success full';
        }
        else{
        echo 'unsuccess';
        }
    }
}
```

**here is my** 
**model**

```
public function checkOldPass($userid){
$this->db->where('username', $this->session->userdata('username'));
$query = $this->db->get('emp');
$row    = $query->row();
if($query->num_rows > 0){
  $row = $query->row();
  if($userid == $row->password){
    return $row->password;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
```

in your controller's constructor or
use below line

```
$this->db->last_query();
```

after this line `$query = $this->db->get('emp');` in your model, get the query from there and run it in your mysql and check is it returning something there. If it is returning it means your query is correct and try to print the return data.

Comment: when i print or echo my password in model it will give result.i think so in query if else condition will not work also when i return data but it will not work

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `$userid` as the username:

`$userid = $this->session->userdata('username');`

Yet you are checking here if the `username` == `the previous password`

```
public function checkOldPass($userid){
$this->db->where('username', $this->session->userdata('username'));
$query = $this->db->get('emp');
$row    = $query->row();
if($query->num_rows > 0){
  $row = $query->row();
  if($userid == $row->password){
    return $row->password;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
 }
```

This logic *does not* make sense. What is the purpose of this function? To return the old password? Then do this:

```
public function checkOldPass() {
        $this->db->where('username', $this->session->userdata('username'));
        $query = $this->db->get('emp');
        //$row = $query->row(); only *AFTER* num_rows()
        if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
            $row = $query->row();
            //if ($userid == $row->password) {
                return $row->password;
            //} else {
            //    return false;
            //}
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Also calling the old password `$cur_password` (`$cur_password = $this->input->post('oldpassword');`) is weird naming scheme and confusing.

---

## Hash passwords

Also hash your passwords to protect your users, and if you are unfamiliar with authentication use a pre-developed library and don't reinvent the wheel. I can recommend Ion_Auth.

Comment: Would have been helpful for you to mention that in the first place. That can only mean one thing your where is limiting results to the point where nothing exists, check if you are getting your session variable username with an echo. If not, then this has nothing to do with CI or coding, your database is missing that record.